# Splice together 2 WP_Query objects

Tags: wp-query

I have been trying for a few days to make a homepage that displays all my posts, and after every 2 posts, a testimonial.

I have found dozens of articles describing how to count while you are in the loop and place something every 'n' number of times. Thats no problem, but what is a problem, is running Loop A, and then every 'n' number of times, placing the next item from Loop B. WP wants you to reset one loop before starting another.

So, I need to query each set separately, parse the queries, and build a new one in the order I want it before I pass to the loop. The problem is, `WP_Query objects` are not arrays. So i can't figure out how to do what I want. I have the whole thing worked out except for one line.
I have deferred to writing the line as I would for arrays so it is evident what I am trying to do.

```
<?php $testimonials = new WP_Query( array('fields'=>'ids', 'post_type'=>'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>
<?php $others = new WP_Query( array('fields'=>'ids', 'post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>
<?php $combined = new WP_Query() ?>

<?php $t = 0; $o = 0; ?>
<?php $total_t = $testimonials->post_count; $total_o = $others->post_count; ?>

<?php while ($total_t > $t && $total_o - 1 > $o ): ?>
    <!-- PROBLEM LINE -->
    <?php array_push($combined, $testimonials[$t], $others[$o], $others[$o+1]); ?>
    <!-- /PROBLEM LINE -->
    <?php $t++; $o = $o + 2; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think is a cleaner way of doing this, using `the_post()` over `next_post()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you just wan't do display something from resultset B on every nth iteration, you could use `next_post()` or simply call `the_post()` on the second query object. Of course you also need to check so there's enough items left in the result and so on:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post'));
$query2 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

// loop through each post and display the title of a page from the second query
// for every third item
while($query1->have_posts()):
  $query1->the_post();

  print get_the_title().'<br />';

  // grab a entry from our second query if we haven't reached the end yet
  if(($query1->current_post + 1) % 3 == 0 && ($query2->current_post + 1) < $query2->post_count):
    $query2->the_post();
    print get_the_title().'<br />';
  endif;

endwhile;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!!! Ahhh! I was on that track yesterday. So simple it hurts. Thanks! I failed to realize you could iterate a specific query with `$query->next_post();`

Comment: @bennett_an - Glad I could help =)